# I am getting an error after the command: make clean. Cleaning the android kernel from garbage

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-firmware

I have the linux kernel sources, but when I try to remove unnecessary garbage (if you follow the video manual), it gives an error:

```
make clean 
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /lib/modules/5.14.0-kali4-amd64/build
```

Comment: And now I noticed that I don't have a /build directory. What  must I do?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The problem was the missing build directory. Installation:
apt-get install linux-headers-kernel worked but required a reboot of the device. Setting the kernel package headers can also help.